# What happens when a record is shared programmatically and granted 'Read' access but organization wide default is private?

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-sharing

What happens - If I create a record programmatically using apex with AccessLevel = 'Read' but OWD is set to private for that Object.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details - are you sharing to a user, group or something else?  What do you expect will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing is additive, except for [Restriction Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule.htm&type=5). That means that the record would be accessible to all users for each the Read access applies to, which may be a User or Group, potentially the entire organization.